# .Net ORM bulk deletion via predicate

Tags: .net, orm

Is there an ORM that will allow me to do the following?

```
db.Delete<MyEntity>(x => ***some predicate***);
```

We use NHibernate and I don't believe this is possible with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SubSonic is able to do something like this.
http://subsonicproject.com/docs/Linq_Deletes